# General way to retrieve target within image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I hit a problem when trying to get my target area within image.

Here is sample image:
[image]

Now I wanna split out only the paper part.

And, actually, I finally get this guy by the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import math

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

origin = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = cv2.imread(args["image"], 0)

image2 = image.copy()

w, h = image.shape[::-1]

image = cv2.blur(image, (9, 9), 0)

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (9, 9), 0)

canny = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 150)

cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imwrite('./tmp_canny.png', canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)

line_arrays = []
lines_p = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, 1, np.pi / 180, 80, minLineLength=150, maxLineGap=10)
lines1_p = lines_p[:, 0, :] 
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines1_p[:]:
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 1)
    if float(x1 - x2) != 0.0:
        k = float(y1 - y2) / float(x1 - x2)
        b = float(y1) - float(x1) * float(y1 - y2) / float(x1 - x2)
        line_arrays.append([k, b, x1, y1, x2, y2])

print '*************************line_arrays: %s**************' % len(line_arrays)
print line_arrays

cv2.imshow('img-withline', img)
cv2.imwrite('./img-withline.png', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

intersections = []

for index1, obj in enumerate(line_arrays):
    cv2.line(origin, (obj[2], obj[3]), (obj[4], obj[5]), (255, 0, 0), 3)
    for index2, obj_1 in enumerate(line_arrays):
        if index2 > index1:
            cv2.line(origin, (obj_1[2], obj_1[3]), (obj_1[4], obj_1[5]), (0, 0, 255), 3)
            # cv2.imshow('calc intersections...', origin)
            # cv2.imwrite('./tmp_calc_intersections.png', origin)
            # cv2.waitKey(0)
            if float(obj[0]) * float(obj_1[0]) <= 0 and float(obj_1[0]) != float(obj[0]):
                x = (float(obj[1]) - float(obj_1[1])) / (float(obj_1[0]) - float(obj[0]))
                y = float(obj[0]) * x + float(obj[1])
                if x > 0 and y > 0 and x < w and y < h:
                    intersections.append([x, y])


print '********************intersections: %s********************' % len(intersections)
print intersections

for j in intersections:
    cv2.circle(origin, (int(j[0]), int(j[1])), 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)  # img to origin
    # cv2.imshow('img-withdot-loop', origin)
    # cv2.imwrite('./img-withdot-loop.png', origin)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow('img-withdot', origin)
cv2.imwrite('./img-withdot.png', origin)
cv2.waitKey(0)


for jd in intersections:
    if jd[0] < w // 2 and jd[1] < h // 2:
        left_top = jd
    elif jd[0] > w // 2 and jd[1] < h // 2:
        right_top = jd
    elif jd[0] < w // 2 and jd[1] > h // 2:
        left_bottom = jd
    elif jd[0] > w // 2 and jd[1] > h // 2:
        right_bottom = jd
    else:
        pass

text_width = math.sqrt((left_top[0] - right_top[0]) * (left_top[0] - right_top[0]) + (left_top[1] - right_top[1]) * (
    left_top[1] - right_top[1]))

text_hight = math.sqrt(
    (left_top[0] - left_bottom[0]) * (left_top[0] - left_bottom[0]) + (left_top[1] - left_bottom[1]) * (
        left_top[1] - left_bottom[1]))


if text_width < text_hight:
    pts3 = np.float32([left_top, right_top,
                   left_bottom, right_bottom])
    pts4 = np.float32([[0, 0], [text_width, 0], [0, text_hight], [text_width, text_hight]])
else:
    pts3 = np.float32([left_bottom, left_top,
                       right_bottom, right_top])
    pts4 = np.float32([[0, 0], [text_hight, 0], [0, text_width], [text_hight, text_width]])

    text_width,text_hight = text_hight,text_width



M_perspective = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts4)
img_perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, M_perspective, (0, 0))

cv2.imshow('img-perspective', img_perspective)
cv2.waitKey(0)

crop_img = img_perspective[0:int(text_hight), 0:int(text_width)]

cv2.imshow('crop_img', crop_img)
cv2.imwrite('crop_img.png', crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the final image I split out which is also what I wanna:
[image]

But, same code is not suitable for this input image:
[image]

I find the problem for Canny, here is image after Canny:
[image]

So, it didn't get the outer border for the paper.

Then I doubt it's related to blur, then, I comment this line:

```
image = cv2.blur(image, (9, 9), 0)
```

Then I get the following canny which seems good:
[image]

But finally I get the output here:
[image]

It's just part of the paper.

I think it's because something wrong with lines detected and intersection points I calculated then, but I haven't tried to refine the code yet(I will trying to refine code to filter out proper lines or points later on)

So, It makes me confused whether or when to use blur or not.

How to do this dynamically upon each input image?

Or is there any better general method to get the paper?

Env:

opencv 3.2.0

Python 2.7.10

Any suggestion is great appreciated?

Thanks.

Wesley

**[edit1]**

According to Alex's comments, code snippet here:

```
tmpimage, contours, h = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_areas = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
print [cv2.contourArea(cnt) for cnt in largest_areas]
cv2.drawContours(origin, [largest_areas[-1]], 0, (0, 0, 255), 3)
cv2.imshow('largestareacnt', origin)
cv2.imwrite('largestareacnt.png', origin)
cv2.waitKey(0)

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_areas[-1])
cv2.rectangle(origin, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(largest_areas[-1])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(origin, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

findcontours after canny get this:
[image]

And final:
[image]

So, it takes the part in red as what has the biggest area.

I think this is because the contours detected is not closed ones.

But we cannot ensure every contour detected is closed.

Comment: The main problem is that you're calling HoughLinesP on the Canny result, which will get lines from the text. Use findContours after Canny; you can grab the largest contour by area (or just use convexHull on your contour result) and *then* apply Hough. Also the blur is fine, maybe make it a little smaller, but your Canny thresholds were probably too high.

Comment: Hi Alexander, see my edit1

Comment: Great work! Again I think your Canny thresholds are just too high. You *should* be able to get a connected edge with the right values on Canny. [This Canny tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) talks a little bit about what those threshold values mean, hope that helps.

Comment: Well, actually I already get the outer border of the paper by setting canny threshold to 30 and 100, but still, contours after the canny is not closed. I think we cannot find a threshold setting to ensure all contours closed for all scenarios for the paper detect. But I will have a look at the link you send.

Comment: You can try `dilate` to expand the Canny results to a thicker line before using `contours`.

Comment: I tried that by canny = cv2.dilate(canny, np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)), seems better, but still not all closed, and this is also what I thought to be.

Comment: Anybody has suggestions?